# Map 2 properties for same data base column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am working on **EF 4.1 code first** development with **MVC and c#**.

**This is my Requirement:**

1. Is there any way to map 2 properties of my model class for same database column ?

B'cos I am having **data retrieval issue** like below.

Currently mapped property for db column having some complex calculation.

So that When I call it from my UI as a ajax call it retrieves calculated value as 0.0, b'cos of that calculation delay (when i put a debug and then slow the things it will correctly generate value).

If I set another field which does not having any calculation it shows correctly.

How to overcome above issue ?

**Part of my model code as below.**

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public Invoice() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); Created = DateTime.Now; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public decimal LatestTotal { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public decimal Total
        {
            get
            {
                return (LatestTotal = this.CalculateTotal());
            }
        }
 }
```

Problematic property is `LatestTotal`

**Action Method** Looks like below

```
public ActionResult GetServiceAndRetailSalesDetails(Guid invoiceOrSaleId, string providerKey, DateTime checkoutDate, double checkoutTime)
        {
            var items = new List<CheckOutServiceAndRetailItem>();
            TimeSpan timeResult = TimeSpan.FromHours(checkoutTime);
            var checkOut = checkoutDate + timeResult;

             var serviceDetails = Repository.GetAllPayableItems(checkOut, invoiceOrSaleId).ToList();

                foreach (var s in serviceDetails)
                {
                    var item = new CheckOutServiceAndRetailItem
                    {
                        AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId = s.Allocation.AllocationId, 
                        Name = s.Allocation.Service.Name,
                        Price = s.LatestTotal,
                        //Price = s.Total,
                        Class = s.Allocation.Service.IsAnExtra ? "RetailOrExtraService" : "",
                    };
                    items.Add(item);
                }
     return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Ajax call** from UI looks like below.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/Portal/GetServiceAndRetailSalesDetails",
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
     data: { invoiceOrSaleId: invoiceOrSaleId, providerKey: providerKey, checkoutDate: checkoutDate, checkoutTime: checkoutTime },
     success: function (response) {
              make = "<table id='tblPayment'>";
              var totalToBepaid = 0.0;
              toBePaidItems = [];
              $.each(response, function (index, sr) {
              if (unPaid) {
              make += "<tr id=" + sr.AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId + " class=" + sr.Class + ">" + "<td style='padding-right:100px'>" + sr.Name + "</td><td class='colTotal' style='padding-right:45px'>" + '$ ' + sr.Price.toFixed(2) + "</td><td></tr>";
               } else {
                   make += "<tr id=" + sr.AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId + " class=" + sr.Class + ">" + "<td style='padding-right:100px'>" + sr.Name + "</td><td class='colTotal' style='padding-right:45px'>" + '$ ' + sr.Price.toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
                   }
                   totalToBepaid += sr.Price;
               //insert into array
               toBePaidItems.push(sr.AllocationOrInvoiceOrSaleId);
       });
       var lateFee = parseFloat($("#hdnLateFee").val());
       if (lateFee > 0) {
               totalToBepaid += lateFee;
               make += "<tr class='Fees'><td style='padding-right:100px'>Late Pickup Fee</td><td class='colTotal' style='padding-right:45px'>" + '$ ' + lateFee + "</td></tr>";
                 }
              make += "</table>";
              $("#serviceAndRetailDetails").html(make);
         }
         });
```

**UI Image as below** (when I put a brake point and run then correct value shows)

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Where and when is `LatestTotal` calculated. EF just loads current value either from database or from cache. So where is the problem?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Actually when I call my repository method it maps to this model and do necessary calculation for the "LatestTotal" property.But b'cos of that delay of the calculation it returns 0.0.When I put debug and check then it's return properly.Any idea?

Comment: So the calculation is concurrent? In such case your AJAX call must wait for calculation to complete. I still don't see connection to mapping issue. If the calculation is done in repository how would mapping two properties to the same column (which is not allowed) could help?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka How could I make Ajax call wait until the calculation finished ?

Comment: Simply by not returning from the action until you are done. I don't see your code = I don't know how did you currently implemented the call.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I have updated my code please check.

Comment: Again. How can your `LatestTotal` be assigned from the query in your action before it is computed? Your repository must have already done the computation.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka That is the exact question also I am having?How could it be happened ? When I put a brake point there and wait for a while then by using watch window it shows the correct value (Not a 0.0).Why's that?

Comment: Are you sure that your request is not just served by the cache when you are not debugging?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Is there any possibility for such a scenario ?.Same code works 2 different ways ? If it's there please let me know?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Is there any method to get "LatestTotal" column value into my model by avoiding the calculation (non map property or something like that) ? Then my problem will solve.B'cos all other non calculated properties are working fine.Any Idea ?

Comment: I don't see how your code could run asynchronously. At the point where you do `return Json(...` the `items` are ready. They should have `LatestTotal`s. If they have `0` values there, the calculation is not correct. BTW, setting a property in a getter of another property is bad practice. Moreover, the way you do it, `CalculateTotal()` always runs when you access the `Total` property.

Comment: @GertArnold OK thanks for your invaluable feedback.I will double check my calculation.